# The requested URL is not found on this server -Laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, routes, apache2

I have two laravel projects **tord** and **milo** in **lol** folder

```
var/www/html/lol

-tord
  -app
  -bootstrap
  -...
-milo
  -app
  -bootstrap
  -...
```

Now, accessing both projects via URL http://localhost/lol/tord/public or http://localhost/lol/milo/public results in:

**Not Found**

The requested URL was not found on this server.

However if i move both project **outside** the **lol** directory and access it via url

http://localhost/tord/public or http://localhost/milo/public
**works fine**

**NOTE :** I've **already enabled apache2 rewrite mode** and also added below override configuration in default 000.default.conf file

```
 <Directory /var/www/html>
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

Comment: `public` folder should be the "DocumentRoot" of your VirtualHosts. Don't run both via `localhost`, create Virtual Hosts (`tord.local`, `milo.local`) for your projects to access them at the same time

Comment: I've created a virtual host for localhost which is http://local.lol , since in future there will be root project inside it. And i want to serve **tord** item using http://local.milo/tord and **milo** item using http://local.lol/milo  @kerbh0lz

Comment: Wy would you do that? That's quite a complicated setup. If both these projects are independent Laravel projects and you're not going to share the session among them, you will have lots of problems separating the session if both projects are using same domain `local.lol`.

Comment: Ok, i can do it in multiple way but i want to know why this error occurs. @dbf

Comment: Nah, I'll just be hones with you, you should only do it the right way; **domain** per **project**. Forget about localhost and forget about apache. Start using nginx and serve each project via a domain.

Comment: Domain will be of tord and these two project are kind of variants that's why i dont want them to be hosted on separate domain. I've some scenario that's why i have to manage it in same domain somehow @dbf